# Column Level Security Products

Tags: 2010, permissions, security, column

I am looking for recommendations on products that handle column level security. What is the best product out there? Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you require a column in SharePoint to be security controlled (i.e make the column visible only to certain users), this is not possible in SharePoint.

If your requirement is that an item's security be based on the value of a column in that item, my suggestion would be to create an ItemEventReceiver that sets the item's permissions when the value of that column changes.

Comment: I understand the SP limitation with regards to column level security but there are few third party products out there that extends SP to provide that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Try KWizCom's SharePoint List Forms Extensions:

[KWizCom: List Forms Extensions Feature](http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-list-forms-extensions-feature/overview/)

It includes List Field-Level Security.